# Replace one string and create a column with another

Tags: r, string, dplyr, tidyverse, stringr

I have a data frame that looks like this

```
position=c("24,201", "8,915", "45,877:1","251,603")
evindence=c("RA", "RA","RA","RA")
test = data.frame(evindence,position)
  evindence position
1        RA   24,201
2        RA    8,915
3        RA 45,877:1
4        RA  251,603
```

I would like to use stringr or other tidyr applications to replace "," = "." and then
create a new column when there is a string like ":".

I would like my dataset to look like this:

```
  evindence position insertion
1        RA   24201     NA
2        RA    8915     NA
3        RA   45877     1
4        RA  251603     NA
```

Any help or direction are appreciated

Comment: at least you were consistent with your typo :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

and here the tidyverse option. Not saying it's better. Just another option.
You'll get an appropriate warning for the NAs - sometimes you want warnings.

```r
library(tidyverse)
position=c("24,201", "8,915", "45,877:1","251,603")
evindence=c("RA", "RA","RA","RA")
test = data.frame(evindence,position)

test %>%
  mutate(position = str_replace(position, ",", "\\.")) %>%
  separate(position, c("position", "insertion"), sep = ":")
#> Warning: Expected 2 pieces. Missing pieces filled with `NA` in 3 rows [1, 2, 4].
#>   evindence position insertion
#> 1        RA   24.201      <NA>
#> 2        RA    8.915      <NA>
#> 3        RA   45.877         1
#> 4        RA  251.603      <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: note if your intention is to create doubles, you still need to call "as.numeric"

Answer (score 3):

Something like this might do the trick :

```
 # should remove the "," from the position column
test$position = gsub(",", "", position)
# should check if string contains :
test$insertion = grepl(":", test$position, fixed=TRUE)
# should extract anything before ":"
test$position = sapply(strsplit(test$position, "\\:"), "[", 1)
```

Comment: sorry for all the edits, had to redo it a few times. should do what you want now though :)